# Capture Image or video on chrome getting black screen

Tags: google-chrome, video, screen-capture

I am trying to capture an image and video in the Google Chrome web browser. I am getting a black screen.  I tried 2-3 screen capture tools but I only get the same black screen, any ideas of what the issue might be?

When I Google the issue I find things related to an admin setting... but I didn't get anything valid.

Are there any Google Chrome admin settings that disable screen captures?

Comment: Is the entire (full screen) captured image black? Or just a rectangle with the image/video? This usually happens when using more independent rendering pipes at the same time to compose the resulting image on the screen. Like SW and HW renderers.

Comment: entire full screen goes black ..